# Python bz2 sequential compressor produces invalid data stream on low compression levels

Tags: python, compression, bz2

I have a series of strings in a list named 'lines' and I compress them as follows:

```
import bz2
compressor = bz2.BZ2Compressor(compressionLevel)
for l in lines:
    compressor.compress(l)
compressedData = compressor.flush()
decompressedData = bz2.decompress(compressedData)
```

When compressionLevel is set to 8 or 9, this works fine. When it's any number between 1 and 7 (inclusive), the final line fails with an IOError: invalid data stream. The same occurs if I use the sequential decompressor. However, if I join the strings into one long string and use the one-shot compressor function, it works fine:

```
import bz2
compressedData = bz2.compress("\n".join(lines))
decompressedData = bz2.decompress(compressedData)
# Works perfectly
```

Do you know why this would be and how to make it work at lower compression levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing away the compressed data returned by `compressor.compress(l)` ... docs say "Returns a chunk of compressed data if possible, or an empty byte string otherwise." You need to do something like this:

```
# setup code goes here
for l in lines:
    chunk = compressor.compress(l)
    if chunk: do_something_with(chunk)
chunk = compressor.flush()
if chunk: do_something_with(chunk)
# teardown code goes here
```

Also note that your oneshot code uses `"\n".join()` ... to check this against the chunked result, use `"".join()`

Also beware of bytes/str issues e.g. the above should be `b"whatever".join()`.

What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Ah, I see. I had missed the fact that the compress function returns partial results rather than all at once at flush(). Interesting that the compressionLevel of 8 or 9 never gets to the point that the partial result is ready - this difference might not even have shown up if I was testing on another set of documents!